# RoR: Instance Variable Interpreted as Missing Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I'm following a tutorial and per the code, I should be able to call the following wihtout error:

```
page = Page.find(1) # works
page.sections.size # Does not work

subject = Subject.find(1) # works
subject.pages.size # works
```

A section belongs_to a page, and a page belongs_to a subject. I'm trying to count the number of sections that are associated with the respective page (in this case, page :id => 1).

The error is `Undefined Method` but I'm not accessing a method, I'm accessing an instance variable. I've reviewed my models and controller, and there is no scope or declerations defined for `subject.pages.size` yet it works without complaint. I'm quite perplexed why it's not working for it's child, `page.sections` when I'm trying to do the same operation.

The diagnostic info (from CLI using pry) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/xKKvSPkz

DB Schema: http://pastebin.com/hiAhXGt8

Comment: Do you have `has_many :sections` in your `page` model?

Comment: Um, boy do I feel like an idiot. I forgot to declare the relationship (both ways) Doh! Thanks, vee. Please submit your response as an answer so I may give you credit.

Comment: FYI you *are* executing a method. That method just happens to be one that returns the value of an instance variable. Remember, if you don't see an @ symbol, you aren't looking at an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the relationship between `page` and `section` is defined:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
end
```

With this relationship the following should work as expected:

```
page = Page.find(1)
page.sections.size
```